Python Scripting Help Needed for Telegram Bot Integration
hi everyone i have py script like:
import re
import os
import sys
import time
import telnetlib

class ZteC320():
    def __init__(self):
        self.zte_unregistered_onts = {}
        self.setup_logging()

        print('\nProgram for auto-registration ONU for gpon zte c320\n')

    def setup_logging(self):
        self.log_file = open('ont_config.log', 'a')

    def log_successful_config(self, serial_number, port, onu_index):
        log_message = f"Successfully configured serial {serial_number} on port gpon-olt_{port} with index {onu_index}\n"
        self.log_file.write(log_message)
        self.log_file.flush()  # Ensure the log is written immediately

    def info(self):
        for gpon_port in self.zte_unregistered_onts:
            print('\nOn port gpon_olt_' + gpon_port + ' serial numbers were found: ' + ', '.join(self.zte_unregistered_onts[gpon_port]['serials']))

    def zte_c320_ping(self):
        response = os.system('ping 10.3.1.10 -n 1')
        if response == 0:
            print('\n\nOLT Tersedia, Mulai\n')
            time.sleep(1)
            return True
        else:
            print('\n\nGPON - 10.3.1.10 does not respond to icmp requests.\n')
            time.sleep(1)
            return False

    def zte_telnet_authentication(self):
        self.__login = 'username'
        self.__password = 'password'

        self.zte_cli_in = telnetlib.Telnet('ipTELNET', 23, 2)
        time.sleep(.1)
        self.zte_cli_out = self.zte_cli_in.read_until(b'Username:', timeout=3)

        if self.zte_cli_out:
            self.zte_cli_in.write(self.__login.encode('ascii') + b'\n')
            time.sleep(.5)
            self.zte_cli_out = self.zte_cli_in.read_until(b'Password:', timeout=3)

            if self.zte_cli_out:
                self.zte_cli_in.write(self.__password.encode('ascii') + b'\n')
                time.sleep(.5)
                self.zte_cli_in.read_until(b'#' or b'>', timeout=3)

                return True

    def zte_vendor_validation(self):
        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'show shelf\n')
        time.sleep(.3)
        self.zte_cli_out = self.zte_cli_in.read_until(b'C320_SHELF', timeout=3)
        if self.zte_cli_out:
            return True

    def zte_show_onu_uncfg(self):
        i = 0
        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'show gpon onu uncfg\n')
        time.sleep(2)
        self.zte_cli_out = self.zte_cli_in.read_very_eager()

        self.zte_uncfg_onts = re.findall(r'gpon-onu_(\d\/\d\/\d)\:(\d)\s+(\w+)', self.zte_cli_out.decode('ascii'))

        if self.zte_uncfg_onts:
            for string in self.zte_uncfg_onts:
                current_gepon_port = string[0]
                current_onu_number = string[1]
                current_onu_serial = string[2]

                self.zte_unregistered_onts.setdefault(current_gepon_port, {'serials': [], 'busy_onts_id': [], 'vlan': None})
                self.zte_unregistered_onts[current_gepon_port]['serials'].append(current_onu_serial)
                i += 1

            print('\nTotal ONU yang belum di config: ' + str(i) + '\n')
            for gpon_port in self.zte_unregistered_onts:
                print('Serial yang ditemukan pada port gpon-olt_' + gpon_port + ': ' + ', '.join(self.zte_unregistered_onts[gpon_port]['serials']))
            return True
        else:
            print('Tidak ada onu yang belum di Config\n')
            sys.exit()

    def zte_check_free_onu_id(self):
        for key in self.zte_unregistered_onts.keys():
            self.zte_cli_in.write(b'   show running-config interface gpon-olt_' + key.encode('ascii') + b' | include type\n')
            time.sleep(2)

            i = 0
            while i < 3:
                self.zte_cli_in.write(b'   \n')
                time.sleep(.3)
                i += 1

            self.zte_cli_out = self.zte_cli_in.read_very_eager()

            onts = re.findall(r'onu (\d+) type (\S+) sn (\w+)', self.zte_cli_out.decode('ascii'))

            if onts:
                for string in onts:
                    current_onu_id = string[0]
                    current_onu_type = string[1]
                    current_onu_serial = string[2]

                    self.zte_unregistered_onts[key]['busy_onts_id'].append(current_onu_id)

                return True
            else:
                print('Tidak ada ONU yang terdaftar pada port gpon-olt_' + key + '.')
                sys.exit()

    def get_pppoe_credentials_from_user(self):
        self.pppoe_username = input('Masukkan username PPPoE: ')
        self.pppoe_password = input('Masukkan password PPPoE: ')

    def zte_auto_add_onts(self):
        self.get_pppoe_credentials_from_user()  # Meminta input dari pengguna

        self.zte_successful_ont_counter = 0

        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'configure terminal\n')
        time.sleep(1)

        for gpon_port in self.zte_unregistered_onts.keys():
            i = 1

            for current_onu_serial in self.zte_unregistered_onts[gpon_port]['serials']:
                for i in range(i, 129):
                    if str(i) not in self.zte_unregistered_onts[gpon_port]['busy_onts_id']:
                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'interface gpon-olt_' + gpon_port.encode('ascii') + b'\n')
                        time.sleep(1)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'onu ' + str(i).encode('ascii') + b' type ALL sn ' + current_onu_serial.encode('ascii') + b'\n')
                        time.sleep(1)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'!\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'interface gpon-onu_' + gpon_port.encode('ascii') + b':' + str(i).encode('ascii') + b'\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'name onu_' + str(i).encode('ascii') + b'\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'description CONF by ACS\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'tcont 1 profile 1G\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'gemport 1 tcont 1\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'switchport mode hybrid vport 1\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'service-port 1 vport 1 user-vlan 1038 vlan 1038 \n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'!\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'pon-onu-mng gpon-onu_' + gpon_port.encode('ascii') + b':' + str(i).encode('ascii') + b'\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'wan-ip 1 mode pppoe username ' + self.pppoe_username.encode('ascii') + b' password ' + self.pppoe_password.encode('ascii') + b' vlan-profile pppoe host 1\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'wan-ip 1 ping-response enable traceroute-response enable\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'security-mgmt 1 state enable mode forward protocol web telnet tr069\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'service tr069 gemport 1 vlan 1038\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'tr069-mgmt 1 state unlock\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'tr069-mgmt 1 acs http://172.16.20.6:7547 validate basic username admin password admin\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'tr069-mgmt 1 tag pri 7 vlan 1038\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'end\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_cli_in.write(b'wr\n')
                        time.sleep(.3)

                        self.zte_successful_ont_counter += 1
                        self.log_successful_config(current_onu_serial, gpon_port, i)
                        print(f'Serial {current_onu_serial} berhasil dikonfigurasi pada index {i}')
                        break

            if self.zte_successful_ont_counter == len(self.zte_unregistered_onts[gpon_port]['serials']):
                print('ONUs Sukses di daftarkan silahkan cek GenieACS')

        if self.zte_successful_ont_counter < len(self.zte_unregistered_onts[gpon_port]['serials']):
            print('Beberapa ONU Belum Sukses di daftarkan.')

    def zte_auto_add_onts_init(self):
        while True:
            if not self.zte_c320_ping():
                input('\nPress enter to exit')
                sys.exit()

            if not self.zte_telnet_authentication():
                print('\nTidak dapat Login ke OLT\n')
                sys.stdin.close()
                sys.exit()

            if not self.zte_vendor_validation():
                print('\nVendor mismatch for 10.3.1.10\n')
                sys.stdin.close()
                sys.exit()

            if not self.zte_show_onu_uncfg():
                sys.stdin.close()
                sys.exit()

            if not self.zte_check_free_onu_id():
                print('Error checking free ONU ID\n')
                sys.stdin.close()
                sys.exit()

            if not self.zte_auto_add_onts():
                sys.stdin.close()
                sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    zte_c320 = ZteC320()
    while True:
        zte_c320.zte_auto_add_onts_init()


Its runing normaly when i manualed execute script, my question how to execute the script from telegram bot with username and ppoe pasword from user and send all respond to user?
i've been try with telegram-bot-python and im stuck. any other ways to fix that?
